# Value for the selected type from radiobuttonlist is showing up NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am really facing a hard time in obtaining the value that was selected from the radiobutton list to controller.

Please help me from this, any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.loan, "create/update")
```

the value will be passed back through the model.  How you have it currently you can get the value of the list from the view using

```
Request.Form["loan"].ToString()
```